# Custom HTTP request header

Tags: java, http, servlets

I'm trying to send a custom header to my web application using [Google Http Client library](https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client) like this:

```
    HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("custom", "somevalue");
    request.setHeaders(headers);
    HttpResponse response = request.execute();
```

However, when I try to enumerate the headers received by my web application, the header I added in my Java client is not there, what could be missing?

Comment: @Tichodroma: the `X-` prefix is **deprecated**. See also http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6648

Comment: @BalusC I see its deprecated, however that's the only way that Google Http Client (in my case) accepts custom header to be submitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using wireshark to inspect the traffic and see if it's actually getting sent. That would tell you if the problem is on the client or server-side.

Tichodrama is right, both sides may require you to use the prefix X- for your custom header.

Comment: tcpmon could help looking at the headers, too

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix your key with X- e.g
httpChannel.setRequestHeader("X-Key", "value")

Answer (score -1):

How about:   `request.addHeader("custom", "somevalue")` ?